# Youtube video won't play on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

I've recently implemented Magnific Popup plugin. You may find it here: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

And this is my test site: http://planet.nu/dev/test/index.html

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the video to play. It will display an error. I'm not sure why it's like that.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jL2u6gqs/

I can't enter the full code here as it's too long. Please look at the jsfiddle instead. Thank you!

```html
<a class="video" title="Test title" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/j6cxZp4ii6c?autoplay=true">Open video</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the href url to this format not the embed URL

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6cxZp4ii6c

the "https" is important

Comment: This works! Thank you! I'm wondering, why you need an https though?

Comment: i don't really know , just changed the http to https and it worked , maybe it's related to Cross Domain smthng like that